# How to fix my function that slices a filtered JSON array?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm having trouble playing with JSON, specifically incorporating .filter() and .slice() together.

My function getPriceDifference(symbol, dateRange), is meant to find the total change between a length of time for stock price. It takes in symbol and an integer value for the number of days to calculate the difference.

The problem is, historicalPrice is an array of multiple symbol prices. I would like to use the `symbol` parameter to filter the correct array, and then slice using the `dateRange`

How can I work with filter() and slice() below to fix my function?

```js
 function getPriceDifference(symbol,dateRange)
  {
    const getChartData = () =>
    {
      const series = [];
      historicalPrice.filter(symbol).slice(-dateRange).forEach((item,) =>
      {
          series.push(item.close);
      });
      return {
        series: [series]
      };
    };

 // Get all values
  const all = getChartData().series[0];

 // Get first + last
  const first = all[0];
  const last = all[all.length - 1];
  const difference = last - first;

  return (difference / first) * 100;
  }
```

SAMPLE DATA:

```
[{"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Mar 10, 2020","close":121.6}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Mar 10, 2020","close":67.34}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Mar 11, 2020","close":122.6}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Mar 11, 2020","close":67.97}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Mar 12, 2020","close":109.25}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Mar 12, 2020","close":62.0}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Mar 13, 2020","close":63.24}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Mar 13, 2020","close":100.4}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Mar 16, 2020","close":60.0}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Mar 16, 2020","close":88.43}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Mar 17, 2020","close":59.6}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Mar 17, 2020","close":79.2}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Mar 18, 2020","close":70.1}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Mar 18, 2020","close":59.28}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Mar 19, 2020","close":71.69}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Mar 19, 2020","close":60.65}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Mar 20, 2020","close":85.16}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Mar 20, 2020","close":57.0}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Mar 23, 2020","close":82.1}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Mar 23, 2020","close":53.15}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Mar 24, 2020","close":58.58}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Mar 24, 2020","close":94.8}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Mar 25, 2020","close":61.08}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Mar 25, 2020","close":102.22}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Mar 26, 2020","close":61.59}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Mar 26, 2020","close":102.45}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Mar 27, 2020","close":61.76}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Mar 27, 2020","close":98.81}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Mar 30, 2020","close":98.25}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Mar 30, 2020","close":62.35}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Mar 31, 2020","close":63.0}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Mar 31, 2020","close":99.4}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Apr 01, 2020","close":59.78}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Apr 01, 2020","close":95.02}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Apr 02, 2020","close":59.23}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Apr 02, 2020","close":89.28}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Apr 03, 2020","close":59.74}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Apr 03, 2020","close":93.68}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Apr 06, 2020","close":62.35}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Apr 06, 2020","close":99.59}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Apr 07, 2020","close":106.47}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Apr 07, 2020","close":64.75}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Apr 08, 2020","close":106.67}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Apr 08, 2020","close":65.31}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Apr 09, 2020","close":66.18}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Apr 09, 2020","close":111.42}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Apr 13, 2020","close":116.11}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Apr 13, 2020","close":66.46}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Apr 14, 2020","close":69.51}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Apr 14, 2020","close":138.49}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Apr 15, 2020","close":70.16}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Apr 15, 2020","close":142.0}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Apr 16, 2020","close":70.59}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Apr 16, 2020","close":141.34}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Apr 17, 2020","close":69.22}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Apr 17, 2020","close":149.53}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Apr 20, 2020","close":142.44}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Apr 20, 2020","close":69.21}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Apr 21, 2020","close":134.76}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Apr 21, 2020","close":66.36}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Apr 22, 2020","close":68.05}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Apr 22, 2020","close":137.74}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Apr 23, 2020","close":68.72}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Apr 23, 2020","close":140.63}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Apr 24, 2020","close":139.64}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Apr 24, 2020","close":69.25}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Apr 27, 2020","close":147.0}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Apr 27, 2020","close":69.99}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Apr 28, 2020","close":69.55}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Apr 28, 2020","close":151.34}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Apr 29, 2020","close":156.63}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Apr 29, 2020","close":70.97}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Apr 30, 2020","close":72.09}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Apr 30, 2020","close":152.7}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI May 01, 2020","close":71.46}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI May 01, 2020","close":136.61}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON May 04, 2020","close":71.58}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON May 04, 2020","close":139.6}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE May 05, 2020","close":73.61}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE May 05, 2020","close":152.44}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED May 06, 2020","close":74.72}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED May 06, 2020","close":152.22}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU May 07, 2020","close":75.49}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU May 07, 2020","close":154.47}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI May 08, 2020","close":157.4}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI May 08, 2020","close":76.07}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON May 11, 2020","close":157.0}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON May 11, 2020","close":76.81}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE May 12, 2020","close":77.73}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE May 12, 2020","close":161.6}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED May 13, 2020","close":75.8}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED May 13, 2020","close":152.66}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU May 14, 2020","close":152.8}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU May 14, 2020","close":75.38}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI May 15, 2020","close":75.05}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI May 15, 2020","close":157.31}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON May 18, 2020","close":77.58}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON May 18, 2020","close":160.78}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE May 19, 2020","close":78.25}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE May 19, 2020","close":161.22}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED May 20, 2020","close":162.36}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED May 20, 2020","close":79.05}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU May 21, 2020","close":78.97}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU May 21, 2020","close":159.2}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI May 22, 2020","close":162.4}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI May 22, 2020","close":78.84}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE May 26, 2020","close":79.13}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE May 26, 2020","close":163.14}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED May 27, 2020","close":157.0}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED May 27, 2020","close":78.27}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU May 28, 2020","close":160.34}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU May 28, 2020","close":78.91}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI May 29, 2020","close":160.84}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI May 29, 2020","close":79.12}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Jun 01, 2020","close":170.82}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Jun 01, 2020","close":79.3}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Jun 02, 2020","close":79.73}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Jun 02, 2020","close":174.2}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Jun 03, 2020","close":176.02}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Jun 03, 2020","close":80.58}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Jun 04, 2020","close":171.69}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Jun 04, 2020","close":80.19}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Jun 05, 2020","close":173.24}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Jun 05, 2020","close":80.81}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Jun 08, 2020","close":81.83}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Jun 08, 2020","close":181.83}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Jun 09, 2020","close":184.79}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Jun 09, 2020","close":83.0}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Jun 10, 2020","close":196.5}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Jun 10, 2020","close":86.52}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Jun 11, 2020","close":194.4}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Jun 11, 2020","close":83.87}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Jun 12, 2020","close":83.56}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Jun 12, 2020","close":182.52}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Jun 15, 2020","close":181.7}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Jun 15, 2020","close":83.15}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Jun 16, 2020","close":86.18}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Jun 16, 2020","close":192.48}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Jun 17, 2020","close":87.77}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Jun 17, 2020","close":196.51}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Jun 18, 2020","close":198.89}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Jun 18, 2020","close":87.31}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Jun 19, 2020","close":86.29}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Jun 19, 2020","close":198.27}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Jun 22, 2020","close":198.0}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Jun 22, 2020","close":87.79}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Jun 23, 2020","close":90.57}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Jun 23, 2020","close":198.8}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Jun 24, 2020","close":190.63}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Jun 24, 2020","close":89.63}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Jun 25, 2020","close":187.43}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Jun 25, 2020","close":89.39}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Jun 26, 2020","close":190.97}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Jun 26, 2020","close":88.26}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Jun 29, 2020","close":189.7}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Jun 29, 2020","close":87.82}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Jun 30, 2020","close":200.75}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Jun 30, 2020","close":90.0}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Jul 01, 2020","close":90.98}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Jul 01, 2020","close":216.1}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Jul 02, 2020","close":90.91}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Jul 02, 2020","close":237.12}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Jul 06, 2020","close":253.21}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Jul 06, 2020","close":92.47}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Jul 07, 2020","close":267.34}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Jul 07, 2020","close":93.06}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Jul 08, 2020","close":262.27}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Jul 08, 2020","close":94.09}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Jul 09, 2020","close":94.67}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Jul 09, 2020","close":270.26}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Jul 10, 2020","close":94.71}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Jul 10, 2020","close":275.2}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Jul 13, 2020","close":95.26}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Jul 13, 2020","close":294.22}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Jul 14, 2020","close":286.2}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Jul 14, 2020","close":93.88}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Jul 15, 2020","close":96.49}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Jul 15, 2020","close":291.4}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Jul 16, 2020","close":293.2}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Jul 16, 2020","close":95.91}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Jul 17, 2020","close":298.0}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Jul 17, 2020","close":95.84}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Jul 20, 2020","close":297.6}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Jul 20, 2020","close":96.06}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Jul 21, 2020","close":311.6}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Jul 21, 2020","close":96.74}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Jul 22, 2020","close":96.6}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Jul 22, 2020","close":312.4}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Jul 23, 2020","close":92.01}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Jul 23, 2020","close":296.15}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Jul 24, 2020","close":89.15}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Jul 24, 2020","close":273.31}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Jul 27, 2020","close":282.6}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Jul 27, 2020","close":93.48}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Jul 28, 2020","close":93.25}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Jul 28, 2020","close":294.88}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Jul 29, 2020","close":297.4}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Jul 29, 2020","close":93.71}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Jul 30, 2020","close":294.2}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Jul 30, 2020","close":93.77}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Jul 31, 2020","close":284.2}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Jul 31, 2020","close":100.83}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Aug 03, 2020","close":107.89}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Aug 03, 2020","close":288.88}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Aug 04, 2020","close":292.4}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Aug 04, 2020","close":108.39}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Aug 05, 2020","close":108.9}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Aug 05, 2020","close":293.66}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Aug 06, 2020","close":295.45}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Aug 06, 2020","close":109.8}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Aug 07, 2020","close":110.29}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Aug 07, 2020","close":283.0}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Aug 10, 2020","close":277.17}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Aug 10, 2020","close":110.0}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Aug 11, 2020","close":273.0}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Aug 11, 2020","close":109.11}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Aug 12, 2020","close":287.0}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Aug 12, 2020","close":110.3}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Aug 13, 2020","close":113.93}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Aug 13, 2020","close":313.45}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Aug 14, 2020","close":113.05}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Aug 14, 2020","close":325.33}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Aug 17, 2020","close":113.96}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Aug 17, 2020","close":334.57}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Aug 18, 2020","close":114.01}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Aug 18, 2020","close":369.02}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Aug 19, 2020","close":115.61}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Aug 19, 2020","close":368.24}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Aug 20, 2020","close":371.41}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Aug 20, 2020","close":115.73}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Aug 21, 2020","close":119.25}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Aug 21, 2020","close":405.01}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Aug 24, 2020","close":385.5}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Aug 24, 2020","close":123.94}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Aug 25, 2020","close":393.6}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Aug 25, 2020","close":123.05}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Aug 26, 2020","close":125.08}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Aug 26, 2020","close":410.73}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Aug 27, 2020","close":123.83}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Aug 27, 2020","close":428.5}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Aug 28, 2020","close":437.3}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Aug 28, 2020","close":124.58}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Aug 31, 2020","close":440.11}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Aug 31, 2020","close":126.0}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Sep 01, 2020","close":130.53}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Sep 01, 2020","close":470.51}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Sep 02, 2020","close":405.12}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Sep 02, 2020","close":127.0}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Sep 03, 2020","close":402.0}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Sep 03, 2020","close":120.5}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Sep 04, 2020","close":110.89}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Sep 04, 2020","close":372.02}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Sep 08, 2020","close":329.88}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Sep 08, 2020","close":112.68}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Sep 09, 2020","close":115.26}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Sep 09, 2020","close":341.51}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Sep 10, 2020","close":112.5}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Sep 10, 2020","close":360.56}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Sep 11, 2020","close":110.0}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Sep 11, 2020","close":360.5}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Sep 14, 2020","close":112.8}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Sep 14, 2020","close":373.3}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Sep 15, 2020","close":430.7}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Sep 15, 2020","close":113.61}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Sep 16, 2020","close":112.04}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Sep 16, 2020","close":435.31}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Sep 17, 2020","close":408.0}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Sep 17, 2020","close":108.71}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Sep 18, 2020","close":106.09}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Sep 18, 2020","close":428.8}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Sep 21, 2020","close":407.07}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Sep 21, 2020","close":103.1}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Sep 22, 2020","close":109.16}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Sep 22, 2020","close":417.6}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Sep 23, 2020","close":106.77}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Sep 23, 2020","close":375.88}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Sep 24, 2020","close":105.0}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Sep 24, 2020","close":351.3}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Sep 25, 2020","close":107.67}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Sep 25, 2020","close":391.3}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Sep 28, 2020","close":415.55}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Sep 28, 2020","close":112.78}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Sep 29, 2020","close":411.6}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Sep 29, 2020","close":113.57}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Sep 30, 2020","close":113.62}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Sep 30, 2020","close":420.47}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Oct 01, 2020","close":434.42}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Oct 01, 2020","close":115.83}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Oct 02, 2020","close":415.0}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Oct 02, 2020","close":112.22}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Oct 05, 2020","close":419.33}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Oct 05, 2020","close":113.55}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Oct 06, 2020","close":112.25}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Oct 06, 2020","close":406.05}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Oct 07, 2020","close":413.85}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Oct 07, 2020","close":114.13}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Oct 08, 2020","close":425.3}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Oct 08, 2020","close":114.59}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Oct 09, 2020","close":426.46}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Oct 09, 2020","close":114.92}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Oct 12, 2020","close":438.58}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Oct 12, 2020","close":119.28}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Oct 13, 2020","close":436.6}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Oct 13, 2020","close":119.65}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Oct 14, 2020","close":447.35}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Oct 14, 2020","close":119.62}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"THU Oct 15, 2020","close":118.15}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"THU Oct 15, 2020","close":442.5}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"FRI Oct 16, 2020","close":118.81}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"FRI Oct 16, 2020","close":438.85}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"MON Oct 19, 2020","close":428.87}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"MON Oct 19, 2020","close":115.66}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"TUE Oct 20, 2020","close":115.63}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"TUE Oct 20, 2020","close":419.05}, 
 {"symbol":"TSLA","date":"WED Oct 21, 2020","close":421.25}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","date":"WED Oct 21, 2020","close":116.45}]
```

`symbol` is indeed a function, please look at how I use the code above and call it:

```
{historicalPrice.filter((i) => i.symbol === data.symbol).map(filteredSymbol => getPriceDifference(filteredSymbol, date)
```

dateRange sample:
it's a state that changes based off user input

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(5);
//value can also be, 5, 21, 62, or 0
```

Comment: filter and slice should work on `historicalPrice` if it's an array. Show some sample data

Comment: I have added sample data above.

Comment: updated the original post

Comment: The dateRange integer signifies how many rows of data to produce.

Comment: `historicalPrice.filter(x=>x.symbol===symbol).slice(-dateRage)` ?

Comment: `historicalPrice.filter(x=>x.symbol===symbol).slice(-dateRange).forEach((item,) =>` 

I am getting NaN's when I do that

Comment: the basics : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask